# Install Epson nx430 with 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, printing

I used the printer set up in system settings and the drivers will not install.  How can I get my printer to work without going back to 13.04 32 bit (it worked in 13.04)?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the drivers for Epson printers including the nx430 from here http://ubuntuone.com/5KBwwCA4TC3n6UkHgaW0ft

Source with list of supported printers:

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/10/download-various-epson-printers-driver.html

Comment: Ubuntu One is going away. Can you update your answer?